# What could be some reasons appium automation tests pass on home wifi but fails on work wifi?

Tags: appium, mobile-automation, android-automation

What could be some reasons appium automation tests pass on home wifi but fails on work wifi?
What should I look out for?
Anyone experience this?
This is really confusing. When I run it at home all tests passes, but once I use the work wifi a few tests would fail. The only difference is I'm the only one using the home wifi and the work wifi has many devices connected to it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is this the same laptop at both locations?  Do you have hot spot capability with your phone plan?  If you do, try connecting to your own hot spot and run your scripts from work.  What kind of failures are you getting?  Timeouts?

Comment: Same laptop/Same devices on two different wifis at two different cities.

Comment: What about the rest of my questions?

Comment: No can't use hot spot. There is no data plan. The failures were tapping but not opening the element, not finding element after taking screenshots to check video exists, but I know the tests has passed before.

Comment: Are you using implicit or explicit waits?  Are you using a page object model?  I noticed you've been posting a lot of questions (that's good) but you need to start posting some code samples along with your questions, please.

Comment: I'm using implicit wait.

Comment: By using the pagefactory method or the driver method?  What's your default timeout setting?

Comment: 40ms and we're not using pagefactory or pom model.

Comment: 40 milliseconds?  that's not nearly long enough.  Implicit is a worst-case scenario, and should be set at least to 10 seconds - I use 15, can be longer, since it will only wait that long IF it cannot locate an element.  40 milliseconds is less than a blink of an eye.

Comment: That is almost certainly your problem, then.

Comment: sorry 40 secs, sorry typo

Comment: You might want to research page object model.  I find it much more reliable in that sense.  Especially if you're trying to locate an element and tap/click it in the same instance, better to separate the steps.  This is getting too lengthy.  Not sure what else to suggest at this point.

Comment: @seleniumappiumnewbie .. As you are using same machine & may be you have static IP address set on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was the network engineer of your work, one "easy way" to create this situation is to block requests from your tests - causing timeouts. I could even do it randomly, just to make your tests even more inconsistent.

In a less extreme case, you have to consider that you are in a different network and maybe your tests are fragile for it. But we cannot evaluate more precisely without the error messages, network configurations, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I appreciate your help. Is there reasons to block requests from tests to cause timeouts? Is it for network maintenance? I don't know much about networks. How do I check if requests are blocked? 
If my tests are fragile and fails on some networks and not others, I guess I have to improve my code.

Comment: You would have to talk to the network people in the company. They can monitor what is happening at the moment you run your tests. OBS: If you find the answer satisfiable, please mark it as accepted.